# Is there a way to drop quests or tasks in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I have a ton of old tasks in my quest log, like Dangerous Game. Because I have the quest, everytime I kill a Crudok or Jottun or the others a vial is placed in my inventory.  I've turned the task in and told him I don't want to help anymore but the task is still in my log.

Is there a way I can drop this task from my log so that the vials will go away or is there a way to destroy these unneeded quest items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dangerous Game" has a bug and will not disappear from your quest log when turned in. And quest items are indestructible (fortunately they often don't take up an inventory slot).

Generally though, quests can't be dropped, you have enough room in your quest log for everything.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you can't destroy at least some quest items. I have a bunch of bottles of wine I can't do anything with and some Lyria relics I don't feel like venturing over to turn in. And that Green stone from the boggart summoning quest, that can go too since the quest was pretty much pointless.

Comment: @MCeley I think you can still give the bottles of wine to the merchant after the quest.

Comment: Well at least that will get rid of one item I have lingering about. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Time to re-address this old question.

When it comes to removing Tasks (not Quests, but repeatable Tasks) in your Quest Log that won't go away, you can remove them by killing the NPC who owns the task!

Press H to enter aggressive mode and kill the NPC you are supposed to talk to when completing the Task. Then fast-travel or fight your way out to a place you can fast-travel, and head to an Inn or your stash house. After sleeping for 3+ days all crimes will be forgotten and you can return to the area.

Sometimes aggressive mode doesn't want to activate so just spam the H key while attacking and you'll get it.

As for accidentally killing important NPCs, I think the game resets the necessary ones but you can definitely permanently kill some NPCs that have unique names. So be careful!

When I found this out I went and cleaned up my task log, because I hate clutter! Go kill those annoying non-task-rewarding NPC losers and get your Quest Log back in shape!!